# Bootstrap navbar fixed top: losing the top of Jumbotron section

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm playing around with sample page Bootstrap navbar fixed top at this address:
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

In my case, I extended the length of default menu (ie. add more menu item or longer item wording). And when the screen size is between 768-990px the Navbar splits into 2 lines (the left part on top and the right part on bottom).

When this situation is happening, the top part of the Joombotron section is overlay and missing behind the navbar (click to see in figure below).

What correction can be made to make sure the Jumbotron is always below the navbar section ?

Thank you,
K

[top of jumbotron is missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjoWJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

In the default template for navbar fixed top, the body element is given padding of 70px to push it below the navbar. If you increased the size of the fixed navbar, you will also need to add additional padding to the body between those two breakpoints:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width: 990px)  {
 body {
  padding: /*new padding rule here*/
  }
 }
```

You can use the chrome dev tools to get the height for the expanded nav bar.

Comment: Thank J_Everhart383 for great tips! I have been able to resolve that problem.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help. Would you mind marking this as the correct answer if this solution solved your problem.

Comment: hi J_Everhart383, it seems that as a new member, I still don't have that function in my account: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score

Comment: No worries! Glad that helped you out. Good luck with your project!